User Profiles in Windows 11 cannot be deleted
I created a new user with the following PowerShell command
New-LocalUser -Name "PVUser" -Description "Profile for PVUser" -Password (ConvertTo-SecureString "Password1" -AsPlainText -Force)

I then try to sign in and interact with this user but I cannot find this this user anywhere. Is it because I did not add it to a group?
I have no issues when I run this script to create an administrator account.
# Create User account and add it to Administrators group
$UserPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString "1234" -AsPlainText -Force
$NewAccountUser = New-LocalUser -Name "User" -Description "Local Admin User" -Password $UserPassword
Add-LocalGroupMember -Group "Administrators" -Member $NewAccountUser

Unfortunately, the first script I ran seems to create the profile but I cannot run a script to delete the file or erase through the GUI.

Below are the user profiles I can interact with through the GUI.

Below are the available profiles that can be modified/deleted. Using advanced system properties.


To remove a user profile via a command, I can list the following
two methods:

In an elevated CMD, run net user User /DELETE.
Try first the command net user to see if it lists this user profile.

In elevated PowerShell run :
Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_UserProfile | ?{$_.LocalPath -like "C:\Users\User"} | Remove-CimInstance -Confirm:$false

Try it first without the Remove-CimInstance to be sure that it gets
the right account.


I would suggest before running automated scripts to remove user profiles,
to take precautions and verify everything. Make also at least a
System Restore point as backup.

this is a VM in Hyper-V I made for testing this.
